# Are there any alternatives to SharedArrayBuffer, or methods for video editing in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm working on a web-based video editing application using ffmeg that heavily relies on SharedArrayBuffer. Unfortunately, I've encountered a roadblock with the "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp | credentialless" and "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin" headers. While these headers allow the usage of SharedArrayBuffer, they restrict other essential features, such as rendering images from an s3 bucket and script of TinyMce text editor.

I am trying to achieve
[video editor like this](https://online-video-cutter.com/)

I am using "next": "12.1.6" and
I tried to implement ffmeg like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useDebounce } from "use-debounce";
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg";

import styles from "../videoEditor.module.scss";
import RangeInput from "../range-input/RangeInput";
import * as helpers from "../../../../utils/videoHelpers";

const FF = createFFmpeg({
    log: true,
    corePath: "https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js",
});

(async function () {
    await FF.load();
})();

export const VideoTrimmer = ({
    videoFile,
    trimmedVideoFile,
    isConfirmClicked,
    setTrimmedVideoFile,
    onConfirmClickHandler,
}) => {
    const [URL, setURL] = useState([]);
    const [thumbNails, setThumbNails] = useState([]);
    const [videoMeta, setVideoMeta] = useState(null);
    const [inputVideoFile, setInputVideoFile] = useState(null);
    const [thumbnailIsProcessing, setThumbnailIsProcessing] = useState(false);

    const [rStart, setRstart] = useState(0);
    const [debouncedRstart] = useDebounce(rStart, 500);

    const [rEnd, setRend] = useState(10);
    const [debouncedRend] = useDebounce(rEnd, 500);

    const handleLoadedData = async (e) => {
        const el = e.target;
        const meta = {
            name: inputVideoFile.name,
            duration: el.duration,
            videoWidth: 50,
            videoHeight: 50,
        };
        setVideoMeta(meta);
        const thumbNails = await getThumbnails(meta);
        setThumbNails(thumbNails);
    };

    const getThumbnails = async ({ duration }) => {
        if (!FF.isLoaded()) await FF.load();
        setThumbnailIsProcessing(true);
        let MAX_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 15;
        let NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = duration < MAX_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES ? duration : 15;
        let offset =
            duration === MAX_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES ? 1 : duration / NUMBER_OF_IMAGES;

        const arrayOfImageURIs = [];
        FF.FS("writeFile", inputVideoFile.name, await fetchFile(inputVideoFile));

        for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_IMAGES; i++) {
            let startTimeInSecs = helpers.toTimeString(Math.round(i * offset));

            try {
                await FF.run(
                    "-ss",
                    startTimeInSecs,
                    "-i",
                    inputVideoFile.name,
                    "-t",
                    "00:00:1.000",
                    "-vf",
                    `scale=150:-1`,
                    `img${i}.png`,
                );
                const data = FF.FS("readFile", `img${i}.png`);

                let blob = new Blob([data.buffer], { type: "image/png" });
                let dataURI = await helpers.readFileAsBase64(blob);
                FF.FS("unlink", `img${i}.png`);
                arrayOfImageURIs.push(dataURI);
            } catch (error) {
                // console.log({ message: error });
            }
        }
        setThumbnailIsProcessing(false);

        return arrayOfImageURIs;
    };
    const handleTrim = async () => {
        // setTrimIsProcessing(true);
        let startTime = ((rStart / 100) * videoMeta.duration).toFixed(2);
        let offset = ((rEnd / 100) * videoMeta.duration - startTime).toFixed(2);
        try {
            FF.FS("writeFile", inputVideoFile.name, await fetchFile(inputVideoFile));
            await FF.run(
                "-ss",
                helpers.toTimeString(startTime),
                "-i",
                inputVideoFile.name,
                "-t",
                helpers.toTimeString(offset),
                "-c",
                "copy",
                "ping.mp4",
            );
            const data = FF.FS("readFile", "ping.mp4");
            const dataURL = await helpers.readFileAsBase64(
                new Blob([data.buffer], { type: "video/mp4" }),
            );

            setTrimmedVideoFile(dataURL);
        } catch (error) {
            // console.log(error);
        } finally {
            // setTrimIsProcessing(false);
        }
    };

    const handleRangeChange = (type, event) => {
        const limit = parseInt((120 / videoMeta.duration) * 100);
        if (type === "start") {
            if (rEnd - rStart > limit) {
                setRend(parseInt(event.target.value) + limit);
                setRstart(parseInt(event.target.value));
            } else {
                setRstart(parseInt(event.target.value));
            }
        } else if (type === "end") {
            if (rEnd - rStart > limit) {
                setRstart(parseInt(event.target.value) - limit);
                setRend(parseInt(event.target.value));
            } else {
                setRend(parseInt(event.target.value));
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoMeta?.duration > 120) {
            const limit = parseInt((120 / videoMeta.duration) * 100);
            setRend(limit);
        }
    }, [videoMeta?.duration]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const videoFormData = new FormData();
        if (videoFile) {
            videoFormData.append("file", videoFile);
            const handleChange = async () => {
                setInputVideoFile(videoFile);
                setURL(await helpers.readFileAsBase64(videoFile));
            };
            handleChange();
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoMeta) {
            onConfirmClickHandler(handleTrim);
        }
    }, [isConfirmClicked]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (debouncedRend == rEnd && debouncedRstart == rStart && videoMeta) {
            handleTrim();
        }
    }, [debouncedRend, debouncedRstart, videoMeta]);

    return (
        <>
            <article className="grid_txt_2">
                <div
                    className={`${styles.bord_g_2} ${styles.p_2} ${styles.video_container}`}
                >
                    {trimmedVideoFile ? (
                        <video
                            muted
                            autoPlay
                            controls
                            src={trimmedVideoFile}
                            className={styles.video_container}
                        ></video>
                    ) : (
                        <video
                            muted
                            autoPlay
                            controls
                            src={inputVideoFile ? URL : null}
                            onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedData}
                            className={styles.video_container}
                        ></video>
                    )}
                </div>
            </article>
            <RangeInput
                rEnd={rEnd}
                rStart={rStart}
                videoMeta={videoMeta}
                thumbNails={thumbNails}
                loading={thumbnailIsProcessing}
                handleRangeChange={handleRangeChange}
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/(.*)",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", value: "same-origin" },
                    { key: "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", value: "credentialless" },
                ],
            },
        ];
    },
    
};
```

This works seamlessly in Chrome and Edge, but  it encounter issues (SharedArrayBuffer is not defined) in Firefox and Safari. How can we ensure it functions impeccably across all major browsers?

When utilizing { key: "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", value: "require-corp" }, I encounter an error while fetching images/scripts from cross-origin sources, resulting in "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200 (OK)". Cany you suggest me how can I resolve this issue?